# which hosts file is using on android by Hotspot Connections??

Tags: android, vpn

We are developing an application(ios, android[2 developer], j2me[2 developer])
We need to use a vpn connection.(We can  take only one account.) I need to share my vpn connection with changed hosts file(for test server).

Firstly I changed my hosts file on device, and download VPNC (ipsec vpn client)(ANDROID).

I can connect and login to test server with these settings.

We have more phones-simulators with these settings. all of them can connect to vpn and use ip on hosts file themself, one by one.

Now I need to connect vpn on One device, and this device share connection(hotspot) to other devices. As a Result, I can run a lot of application wıth using ip on hosts and using one connection.

I think I could do this on Android. it connects vpn on mobile network, and shares connection on wifi. I tried this, but other devices could not connect and login. What should I do?